# 2 or more images with same name have different activity

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a group, and many images to be assigned in a group, those images are generated automatically, and im using only one image viewer. to explain better here is my code:

`//Group Name`

```
local localGroup = display.newGroup()

//Create new Image

//Image is called by a random number and to be inserted in a group

if (params.image == 1) then
    object = display.newImage("Images/last-guardian-sprites/amg1_rt1.gif")
elseif (params.image == 2) then
    object = display.newImage("Images/last-guardian-sprites/bmg2_rt1.gif")
elseif (params.image == 3) then
    object = display.newImage("Images/last-guardian-sprites/ftr2_rt1.gif")
end
```

now in every 1 second a random number generates thus displaying an image depends on the number generated, these images are assigned in a group, my problem is whenever i set a command for "group" it doesn't respond on the created images, instead it responds on recently created image(if images is created @ 11 secs, that image will receive the command, images from 1-10secs are still on its current position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you don't have a table of the objects you created.

You need to create an empty table like this:

```
table = {}
```

Then you need to insert each object into the table:

```
table[#table+1] = display.newImage(BLANK)
```

Then when you want to manipuate just the one image, do the following

```
table[2].x = display.contentWidth/2
```

Remembeer you can also add these objects to your group like so:

```
localGroup:insert(table[#table+1])
```